# Change all values in column if a condition is met within a group in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains many rows, and a condition that is checked for each row and saved as a boolean in a column named `condition`. If this condition is `False` for any row within a group, I want to create a new column that is set to `False` for the whole group, and to `True` if the condition for every row within the group is set to `True`.

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
       group  condition  final_condition
0      1      False            False
1      1      False            False
2      1       True            False
3      2       True             True
4      2       True             True
5      3       True            False
6      3      False            False
```

I have tried many different things but can't find a solution, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `groupby()`+`transform()`:

```
df['final_condition']=df.groupby('group')['condition'].transform('all')
```

output of `df`:

```
group   condition   final_condition
0   1   False       False
1   1   False       False
2   1   True        False
3   2   True        True
4   2   True        True
5   3   True        False
6   3   False       False
```